# Generate and/or validate license keys for App Engine for a closed beta

Tags: google-app-engine, key

I will release my GAE application in a few months on a closed beta state, so that just a few users can use it and I get some date and know where and how to improve it. My idea was that I use a key system to let them access the application.

**What I want to do:**

I want to generate a punch of keys and store them with Datastore. When a users comes to the application the first time he logs in with his Google account and has to enter a key to activate his account.

**My question:**

My previous software didn't require such license keys or similar so this is a new area for me. Do you think this is good way to realize a closed beta? My second idea was to generate a bunch of keys and validate them with a system like other popular software does it, but I think this is unnecessary and I wan't to avoid a that someone can make a key-gen. Just generating, storing, then checking the key if it exists in the Datastore, setting it to used and activating the account would be my suggestion.

How can I generate a lot of valid and easily add more (without duplicates) keys. I'm thankful for every experience and suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a refinement to Ashley's suggestion, if you'd like to generate shorter and/or easier to type IDs, you can generate some random data and encode it using base32:

```
base64.b32encode(os.urandom(8)).strip('=')
```

Make it a bit more readable by inserting hyphens:

```
'-'.join(base64.b32encode(os.urandom(8)).strip('=')[5*x:5*(x+1)] for x in range(3))
```

This gives you codes like the following:

```
'C6ZVG-NJ6KA-CWE'
```

Then just store the result in your datastore and hand them out to users. I'd suggest storing the code without the hyphens, and stripping those characters before checking the database. If you want to get really fancy, base32's alphabet is chosen to avoid characters that look similar; you could substitute those characters before you do the check to account for typos.

8 bytes of random data gives you 2^64 possible invite codes; if you hand out, say, 2^16 (65,536) of them, an attacker will still have to try 2^48 (about 300 trillion) codes to find a valid one. You can make your codes shorter at the cost of reducing the search space, if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already was looking for a more readable solution. Unfortunately I write the application in Java, because I'm not really familiar with Python. If possible, could you please update your answer.

Comment: @DominicBartl I don't know Java well enough to translate it easily, but the steps are simple: 1) generate 8 bytes of randomness using a secure random number generator 2) encode them using base32, 3) add hyphens. In future, if your question is language-specific, you should add the tag for that language to your question.

Comment: Thanks the steps enough so that I can translate it to Java and yes I should have added a language tag, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I use [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) for generating random keys:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
```

From the docs: "The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator".

Generate a long list of them in the datastore, and then when a user arrives at something like: yourapp.com/betainvite/blahblahkey you can simply check if the key is in the table, and if it's rsvp property is null (or already set to the date it was used, in which case you deny the invite).

You could store the key against your User too, so you can find out who used each one and when.

Also good idea to maintain an invited date on the keys, then as you use each one you can mark it as invited, so you don't double invite people.

Comment: The simplest approach is often the best, and since you're in control of both generation and validation, this approach will work just fine.

Comment: I should add, the UUID actually ships with hyphens out of the box, I strip them out in my code, because I think keys look more _key-like_ without the hyphens. Just yank the `.replace("-", "")` from my snippet to make hyphenated keys from UUID. Add a `.substring()` if you want to shorten the keys generated by UUID.

Comment: Beware of truncating UUIDs - they are (somewhat) structured, and a truncated version may have less unique information than you expect.

Comment: Good point Nick! (though if he gets so many sign-ups for his beta that his UUID substrings clash, it'll be the _least_ of his problems :P)